# Is there an event "on Refresh" for jqgrid navgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I try to find how to trigger an event before my grid refresh itself.
Actually I need something like "onSearch" but for the reset button.

here is my code for navgrid :

```
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#jqGridPager' 
        ,{edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true},// button of the footer : search and refresh
        {}, // settings for edit
        {}, // settings for add
        {}, // settings for delete
        {
            onSearch:function(){/*... first action ... */}, 
            /*   here :    afterRefresh: function(){console.log("refresh?");}, */
            multipleSearch:true,
            overlay:false, 
            sopt: ['eq']
         } // search options
    );
```

Does someone has an idea and/or documentation about navgrid events?

Thanks

Comment: Your version of jqgrid?

Comment: list of [jqGrid events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) and also [wiki:navigator](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator)

Comment: I use version 5.1.0      thanks Amin for this doc but why isn't "onSearch" in the doc? and which event matchs with my expectation? (everything that I tried works on refresh button but not with reset button)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeRefresh` and `afterRefresh`:

```
 $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#jqGridPager',
    {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true,
        beforeRefresh: function(){console.log("beforeRefresh");},
        afterRefresh: function(){console.log("afterRefresh");}},
    {}, // settings for edit
    {}, // settings for add
    {}, // settings for delete
    {
        onSearch:function(){/*... first action ... */}, 
        multipleSearch:true,
        overlay:false, 
        sopt: ['eq']
     } // search options
);
```

It's important to understand that `navGrid` just add buttons in the navigator bar. It calls some other methods of jqGrid on click on the most buttons. The options which you see in the "Searching" block are just the options of [searchGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#calling_conventions) method, which `navGrid` will use on click on the "Searching" button. There are **no** Refresh method, but there are exist "reloadGrid" event. `navGrid` calls the callbacks `beforeRefresh` and `afterRefresh` *itself*. It's the reason why `beforeRefresh` and `afterRefresh` are specified together with other *options of `navGrid`*.